# database creating hangs at 59% with domain/username as oracle home user

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

while creating database with domain\user as oracle user it hangs at 59% progress, but while creating with local windows user the database is created successfully.

Is there any changes that has to be done while creating a domain user for oracle dbca creation?

Comment: does the installation path has space in it?

Comment: The installation path has space in it

Answer (score 0):

[oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) cannot handle spaces in file path on product installations. The destination path of the Oracle installation is needed to be **path with no spaces**

Comment: I misunderstood your question, the actual home path didn't have any space between thrm